# Double return with a condition in Typescript

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Well, I'm trying to do something that I think is completely unnatural.

What I need to do, is to return different values depending on a `if`, like that :

```
if(add)
    return {exists: myExists, key: myKey};

return myExists;
```

But then I got : `error TS2339: Property 'exists' does not exist on type '{ exists: boolean; key: number; } | boolean'.` at the compilation when I call the result of the function elsewhere.

Here is where I get the error (The return statement is in `IsInDays(value, add)`:

```
AddDay(value){
    var datas = this.IsInDays(value, true);
    if(!datas.exists)
        this.days.push(value);
    else{
        this.days.splice(datas.key, 1);
    }

    console.log(this.days);
}
```

I do that because I don't know how to get the `exists` value for my `[ngClass]` statement (which calls the function) when it's in an object :/

If anybody knows a different way that would be awesome.

Comment: Isn't it slightly unsafe to return data of different types?

Comment: The function that's calling this expects to receive an object as the value. You need to return an object in both cases.

Comment: And do you know how to get the specific value of an object with [ngClass] ? Because I can only manage to get the entire object, not the boolean I need

Comment: I think you are not showing the code that produces the error - the calling side.

Comment: myExists is set to false at the beginning of `IsInDays(value, add)`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Nevermind.

I used my loop twice, I was just trying to optimise my code. Here is the function for the `[ngClass]` statement :

```
IsInDays(value){
    for (var item of this.days) {
        if(item == value){
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Return false at the end of your function

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with optional types like this:

```js
function doesStuff(condition: boolean): string | { name: string, age: number } {
    if (condition) {
        return {name: 'A', age: 5};
    }
    return 'not found';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

there is no `exists` on boolean, therefore `!datas.exists` will not work. Use `typeof datas === "boolean"` for your check.

Answer (score -1):

I was facing one SONARQUBE issue, "return value of filter must be used".

Here is issue code:-

```
private Foo(Data: Array<any>) {
    let result = [];
    Data.filter((item: any) => {
      if (!this.IsAlreadyExist(result, item.Name)) {
        result.push({
          Name: item.Name,
          Id: item.Id
        });
      }
    });
    return result;
}
```

Here is the solution:-

```
private Foo(Data: Array<any>) {
    let result = [];
    return Data.filter((item: any) => {
      if (!this.IsAlreadyExist(result, item.Name)) {
       return result.push({
          Name: item.Name,
          Id: item.Id
        });
      }
    });
  }
```